# New Folder Gets Created But Files Don't Get Uploaded

Tags: php, upload, filesystems

I have a perfectly working file uploading system. I started thinking about the effect of having several files in a single directory, hence I decided to create folders on the fly if the person uploading his or her picture is registering under a new group since there are various groups. I realized that the folder for the new group gets created but the photo don't get uploaded. If I specify an already existing folder in my code, the photo gets uploaded to the folder. Where am I getting it wrong?

Here is my code:

```
            //Check if the upload folder exist and create it if not
            $initialdestination = "../photosfolder/";
            $groupDestination = "$initialdestination$groupusername";
            if(file_exists($groupDestination)){
             $destination = $groupDestination;
            }else{
            $destination = mkdir($groupDestination, 0777);
            }
            
                        //Update the database with the image data if there is no error
                        if(isset($imageUploaded) && empty($error)) {
                            // define the path to the upload folder
                            $destination = $destination;
                            
                            // move the file to the upload folder and rename it
                            move_uploaded_file($uploadfile, "$destination$uploadname");
                            try
                            {
                                $conn = DatabaseManager::getConnection();
                                $sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `filename` = :filename, `destination` = :destination WHERE `username` = :username";
                                $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
                                $st->bindValue(':filename', $uploadname); 
                                $st->bindValue(':destination', $destination);
                                $st->bindValue(':username', $username);
                                $st->execute();
                                
                                }
                                catch(PDOException $e)
                                {
                                        $error[] = "Unable to store your picture.";
                                }
                            }
```

Please note, every other thing is working. This is the part of the code that needs third eye. Thank you.

Comment: if linux, you should check directory permission whether it's allowed to write (create a file). saw that you already set 0777.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($uploadfile, "$destination/$uploadname"); could it be that it's missing a slash?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, thank you very much. Adding the slash solved the problem. I'm grateful.